# Intellij "Unused method / import / etc." with Angular2

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I like seeing the "Unused ..." warnings in Intellij Ultimate IDEA but working with Angular 2 / Typescript framework I get all these "Unused import" statements and "Unused Methods" in the component where the use is exclusively in the template.

Presumably Intellij has no way of detecting the uses in a template? Is there a way to make it "look" there? Or am I missing something? Or do people simply ignore them or disable the warnings all together?

Answer (score 0):

I have update IntelliJ Idea and AngularJS plugin in Settings -> Plugins -> AngularJS -> Update. And after restart Idea, all highlights and warnings work fine.